# How to know which driver or kernel module prevents process to be killed?

Tags: windows, freeze, task-manager, debug, kill

Sometimes I have processes which I can't kill. Process Explorer, Task Manager and others say that "Access denied". I was told that this can be because kernel driver has a bug or something.

How to know THE NAME of this kernel module or driver?

Comment: is this a recent problem? have you updated drivers recently or installed new hardware?

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/585073/179299

Comment: Actually not.  This question seeks to know the name of the process, not to kill it.